# How can I get the correctly applied types in the body of a class in Scala 3 reflection?

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, scala-macros

Let's say I'm reflecting on this class using Scala 3 reflection:

```scala
class Foo[T](val thing: T):
  var store: Option[T] = None
```

Let's say I reflect with given type Foo[Boolean], and I get the TypeRef for this class as this:

```scala
AppliedType(TypeRef(TermRef(TermRef(TermRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class <root>)),object co),object blocke),object scala_reflection),class Foo),List(TypeRef(TermRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class <root>)),object scala),class Boolean)))
```

So far, so good.  I can further reflect on the constructor fields and see that 'thing' is correctly applied as Boolean.

Where can I look to find the applied types for anything defined in the body?  Everywhere I've looked so far I just see 'T', not Boolean.  For example, using my reflection library I can output:

```
co.blocke.scala_reflection.Foo[Boolean]:
   fields ->
      thing: [T] Boolean
   non-constructor fields (non-case class) ->
      store: Option of T
```

I'm clearly not looking in the right place for the ValDefs defined in the body. They all come back 'T'.

Comment: Pattern matching on whole AST is the least effective method of getting most of the information. Symbol is the API that is better at querying relations between definitions. And each definition defined as type parametric will have type parameters instead of applied types, they are seen in AppliedType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern matching on AST is the last resort when it comes to any operation in Tasty. Quotes offer quite a lot of utilities already.

I you managed to find a `TypeRepr` (any subtype of it will do) then `Quotes` offer you the right API for [asking for applied types](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/blob/80206775f4c81e569424a24c0c67b1c936c28c3a/library/src/scala/quoted/Quotes.scala#L2737):

```
import quotes.*, quotes.reflect.*

val repr: TypeRepr = ...
typeArguments = repr.typeArgs
```

If you need to have these types applied to some method, then you'd have to

1. extract type arguments from type definition
2. manually apply them to method type

E.g.

```
val method: Symbol = ... // method belonging to type represented by repr    

if repr.typeArgs.isEmpty then repr.memberType(method)
else repr.memberType(method).appliedTo(repr.typeArgs)
```

Examples of such type parameter reapplication can be found in [Chimney](https://github.com/scalalandio/chimney/blob/c5d4edc092c8eea52434d359b900ddf3cd692ec2/chimney-macro-commons/src/main/scala-3/io/scalaland/chimney/internal/compiletime/TypesPlatform.scala#L32) (disclaimer: I'm a co-author) as it's macro heavy library that needs to inspect types a lot.